# C# Translating text using Azure API

Tags: c#, azure, translation

I'm a newby w.r.t. C#, and want to translate multiple text.
Previously I used the Bing translation service, but now I want to move over to the new Azure methods.

I looked at a lot of C# examples, but just cannot get it working within my Application. The bottom line what I want to do, is provide the "Key", the text, from/to language, and then receive the translated text.

Does anybody have a good example on how to do this.

I did find a workable example here: :-) https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator/GetAzureToken

But, then I could not get this going within my application. :-(

Any help would be appreciated.

Kind regards,
Michael

Comment: What have you tried? Did you download the code and run the program? Did you generate your own subscription key to use the translation service?

Comment: Yes, I downloaded the code, and it does work.

Comment: But, I cannot get it working within my application. It uses "TanslatorService", and I don't really know what that is.

Comment: The translator service is a service reference to their translator code. Once you have a token, you can call their API directly. See http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/text-translate.html for an API reference.

Comment: Hi Eran, I saw that as well, but it is using the old methods. (ClientID and ClientSecret) I want to start using the new method where you only need to provide the a Key.

Comment: In my opinion, The document that Partly provide is currently being used, we can create that API in Azure portal. Which document do you follow? Could you provide more detailed for us to reproduce your issue?

Comment: I used the code from "https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator/GetAzureToken" I got it going, but I cannot get the same going in my application. The problem is that it uses "TranslatorService", and I'm not sure how that works or what it is.

Comment: Michael - Did you get it working yet? Im having the same issues.

Comment: @CsharpBeginner. No, I could not get it going. I decided to look at google, and there I got it going easily.